# URL getting changed

Tags: permalinks

I am facing a problem with my website’s URL which cropped up recently

Whenever I am trying to go to particular URL eg https://www.example.org/what-we-do/ I am getting re-directed to https://www.example.org/?what-we-do%2F and this opens up my frontpage . My permalink structure is http://www.example.org/sample-post/ . I tried disabling all my plugins but that didnt solve the problem . Any idea what might be causing this and a good starting point to troubleshoot this ?

Comment: What is supposed to show at `example.org/what-we-do`? A Page (post type `page`), post, term archive, or? Have you tried clearing your caches? Have you checked your `.htaccess` for anything suspicious?

Comment: A page , the .htaccess is the basic WP one nothing suspicious at all

Comment: So it is still happening? How about clearing caches or just disable caching? Anything in the server/PHP/WordPress (error) logs? If you access the page by ID (`example.com/?page_id=123`), does the redirect still happen? Have you tried using a different browser/device and logging in as a different user?